# SCRIPT to Copy a file to another folder and if the name file has the same name, rename it

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have this script that Works very well, but, some users have some .pst with the same name, I dont want to overwrite it,  what I need is, how can I rename the files during the process, or before.. after the process. Thank you

```
rem Copia de Archivos PST a Carpeta FronMig*****

@echo off

taskkill /IM outlook.exe

if not exist c:\FronMig mkdir c:\FronMig

if not exist c:\FronMig\pst mkdir c:\FronMig\pst

c:

dir /b c:\*.pst /s > c:\FronMig\pathdata.txt

pause


for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (c:\FronMig\pathdata.txt) do (copy "%%a" c:\FronMig\pst) 


start outlook.exe

pause
```

Comment: How do you know which `.pst` came from which user? which `.pst` came from which location? and what the `.pst` file was named prior to you renaming it?

Comment: using 
dir /b c:\*.pst /s > c:\FronMig\pathdata.txt
pathdata.txt logs

Comment: The ideia is... for exemple
Founded test.pst on C:\temp (first file) and move it to C:\PST
Founded test.pst on C:\temp02 (second in sequence) and move it to C:\PST without to overwrite the test.pst that is alreay in C:\PST . I need to find a way to rename the second file in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take precautions:

- not to process your destination folder
- properly handle already numbered files.

The following batch appends an explorer like number in parentheses (1)
Tested with different folders and extension.
If a file name is already present the sub `:CopyInc` is called recursively, incrementing until the new name is free.

```
@echo off
taskkill /IM outlook.exe
Set "Dest=c:\FronMig\pst"
Set "Base=C:\*.pst"
Mkdir "%Dest%" 2>NUL

For /f "delims=" %%P in (
  'dir /b/s/a-d "%Base%" ^|Findstr /IBLV /C:"%Dest%" '
) Do (echo %%P
  Set "Cnt=0"
  Set "Name="
  For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=()" %%B in ("%%~nP") Do Set Cnt=%%C&Set "Name=%%B"
  rem >> "c:\FronMig\pathdata.txt" Echo:%%~fP
  Call :CopyInc "%%P" "%Dest%\%%~nxP"
) 
start outlook.exe
pause 
Goto :Eof

:CopyInc
If not exist %2 (
    Copy %1 %2 &&Echo Copied %1 %2
    Goto :Eof
) else (
    Echo Already present: %2
)
Set /A Cnt+=1
If not defined Name Set "Name=%~n2 "
Set "NewName=%~dp2%Name%(%Cnt%)%~x2"
Echo Try: copy %1 "%NewName%"
Call :CopyInc "%NewName%"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help LotPings,

This is the result

C:\pst\vitor.retta@assuranceit.com.br.pst
        1 file (s) copyed(s).
C:\Users\Retta\Documents\Arquivos do Outlook\vitor.retta@assuranceit.com.br.pst
Try: copy "C:\Users\Retta\Documents\Arquivos do Outlook\vitor.retta@assuranceit.com.br.pst" "c:\FronMig\pst\vitor.retta@assuranceit.com.br(1).pst"
'"c:\FronMig\pst\vitor.retta@assuranceit.com.br(1).pst"' Is not recognized as an internal command
Or external, an operable program or a batch file.
Press any key to continue. . .

Comment: Again, just one file was copyed, and it wasnt renamed the second
your script didnt created the pathdata.txt

Can you help me again

Thank you so much

Comment: While testing I added the Rem in front of `>>` simply remove it. Looking into the other issue.

Comment: Changed batch. If you get errors, please append them to the end of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help LotPings, There´s no erros now , but, nothing was changed.
The script finds 2 .pst files, with the same name on 2 differnt folders
The script copy the first .pst to c:\FronMig\pst but the script still overwritting the first .pst when they copy the second.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will check if file config.txt exits if it does it copies the file to another folder and renames it at the same time.

```
IF EXIST "C:\Test\config.txt"(copy /y C:\temp\config.pst C:\Somepath\config_copied.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks Wojtek,
The problem is that I want to do it without any user interaction. 
The ideia is... for exemple Founded test.pst on C:\temp (first file) and move it to C:\PST Founded test.pst on C:\temp02 (second in sequence) and move it to C:\PST without to overwrite the test.pst that is alreay in C:\PST . I need to find a way to rename the second file in sequence

Comment: Ah, and there´s no way to know the name of the .pst file before run the script.

Comment: or, how can I do a sequence of copy and rename the files in sequence, like.. fil01.pst.. file02.pst...